# Improving Lookup Performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl, lookup

I am doing a Lookup Operation (in SSIS) between Table A against a Table B. The following is a sample of the two tables:

```
TABLE A (
AID
BID
C
)

TABLE B(
BID
D
E
)
```

I am performing a lookup, joining both "BID", getting `D` and `E` from Table B. `BID` is an int.
However, since table A has more than 150000 records, it takes a lot of time to process it, between 10 and 15 minutes. I have already created an Index on BID, in Table B but it didn't help:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NonClusteredIndex-20190105-141910] ON [dbo].[TableB]
(
    [BID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Any clue what I can do more?

Thanks

Comment: What cache mode is the lookup component using? Have you tried setting it to full?

Comment: It is in full-cache mode

Comment: What is a lot of time?

Comment: Between 10 to 15 minutes

Comment: How big is table B?

Answer (score 1):

When performing lookups on a huge amount of data, it is better to use an SQL join instead of using lookups. Try use an OLEDB Source that read from an SQL Command where you use a `LEFT JOIN` query.

Also make sure that all fields included in the Join operation are indexed.

For more info you can refer to:

- [SSIS Lookup or T-SQL Join](https://derekdb.wordpress.com/2012/03/13/ssis-lookup-or-t-sql-join/)
- [TSQL vs SSIS Lookup](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83423/tsql-vs-ssis-lookup)
- [HOW A SSIS LOOKUP WORKS DIFFERENT FROM A T-SQL JOIN (SSIS SERIES)](https://www.hansmichiels.com/2017/01/13/how-a-ssis-lookup-works-different-from-a-t-sql-join-ssis-series/)

Comment: I did try that, replacing therefore the OLDBSource (using mappings) and the Lookup by a simple query but it didn't help

Comment: If you have sufficient memory you can try to use [cache lookups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/lookup-transformation?view=sql-server-2017) which is *an in-memory cache that stores the reference dataset and stores a hash table that indexes the data*

Comment: Otherwise it is better to use `Joins` and to create appropriate indexes as GordonLinoff suggested

Comment: If you are interested in cache lookups you can refer to this [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mattm/2008/10/18/lookup-cache-modes/)

Comment: @DiogoSantos one more thing, did you created an index on `BID` in TableA ??

Comment: Actually, No I didn't, only the one in the Question... Would that make a substantial difference?

Comment: @DiogoSantos of course you have to create an index on all columns used in the join operation

Comment: @DiogoSantos i noticed in my answer that *`Also make sure that all fields included in the Join operation are indexed`*

Answer (score 0):

You can try including the column values you are looking up:

```
CREATE INDEX tableb_bid_d_e ON [dbo].TableB(BID, D, E)
```

However, your problem is probably the number of rows being processed -- so your query is generating a lot of data.  If you select just a handful of rows from `A`, the index should speed up queries a lot.  If you are selecting all the rows -- well, a lot of data needs to be processed.

Comment: Aparently it didn't help. Which is weird because indexing the fields that are being used in the lookup should have massively improved the operations I guess

Comment: @DiogoSantos . . . Oh, I see.  `TableB` is in your staging area.  Presumably, that is not in the same database as `TableA`.  My suggestion is to copy the data over to a table in the database, and do all the work there.